# CMake macro to include all module source files?

Tags: azerothcore

Modules I've seen use `AC_ADD_SCRIPT` to add individual .cpp files. I am porting playerbot which has many source files, and I am wondering if there is a way to tell AC to add all files underneath?

The playerbot CMakeLists.txt file uses Cmake globbing to do this, but I think it doesn't set the same variables that `AC_ADD_SCRIPT` does to make things Just Work.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Could you link repository to your playerbot to check your CMakeLists.txt file?

Are you trying to load a set of "scripts files"? if yes the combination of: AC_ADD_SCRIPTS and AC_ADD_SCRIPT_LOADER should be enough

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for commenting! Here is what I ended up doing: https://github.com/thanhtong89/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master_playerbot/modules/bot/CMakeLists.txt
This seems to get things compile nicely. Is there a more recommended approach?

Comment: Yes i think you can use directly: AC_ADD_SCRIPTS("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/playerbot/") instead of your long list of single files (the plural form of that macro searchs in all subdirectories of playerbot folder)

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly:

```
AC_ADD_SCRIPTS(your_directory_path)
```

(note the plural form)

this macro will search recursively inside defined path for both `*.cpp` and `*.h` files including them in core scripts